# Serialized date format in response body JSON

Tags: java, json, date

When I'm creating object

```
{
  "id": 41788,
  "systemStartDate": 1447459200000
}
```

When I'm getting object by id:

```
{
  "id": 41788,
  "systemStartDate": "2015-11-14"
}
```

I know the reason that entities which are come from DB have that format: I have temporal date annotation on table.

```
public class DateEntity {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date systemStartDate;

}
```

This is object returned from CREATE service:

```
@Transactional
public DateEntity savePlan(DateEntity dateEntity) {
    //...
    return dateEntityRepository.save(dateEntityPersistent);
}
```

How can I achieve that returned object also has human-readable date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
{
  "id": 41788,
  "systemStartDate": 1447459200000
}
```

systemStartDate is in long format.

To convert into in date you can use `Date d=new Date(1447459200000l);` if you want to modify in consumer side.

If you do not want to change in consumer side then you can simply return date object instead of long in producer side